# How to Activate the Loading Icon[iPad]

Tags: javascript, ios, web-services, cordova, icenium

Sorry for being newbie here, I just want to ask about the loading icon of an iPad on the Left side of Toolbar. Is it a automatic activation based on sized of file?  because I'm developing an ios apps using Icenium that will request to web-service and get the response but it doesn't show the loading bar.

sorry for being newbie. 
Thanks for those who will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking - but if you are using Icenium with Kendo UI Mobile, you can activate the "loading" modal dialog by using:

```
app.showLoading()
```

...and then manually hide it with:

```
app.hideLoading()
```